# How to find the solution to an at first glance complicated looking infinite series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

During doing some Analysis problems I encountered the following infinite series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5 n^{3}+3 n^{2}+\cos (n)+(n+1)^{2}}{6 n^{7}+\sqrt{n^{3}+n+1}}
$$

Although one can easily prove the convergence of the above, finding the term it converges to doesn't seem that straightforward. I suppose that one splits up the numerator but I don't really know how to proceed then. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: Really? It's good to have dreams, but frankly the chances this has a closed form is close to zero...

Comment: Define the function $$f(x)=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5 n^{3}+3 n^{2}+\cos (n)+(n+1)^{2}}{6 n^{7}+\sqrt{n^{3}+n+1}}x^n,
$$ which is obviously convergent for $|x|\le1$. Then the closed formula for the series will be $f(1)$. If you expect something different tell us which functions are allowed to be used in a "closed" form.